# Access asp.net gridview edit control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, calendar, edit

I would like to access a calendar control through c# for when a gridview row is edited. However, I am unsure of how to access this through C# behind.

I would like to do the following:

```
cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
date = cal.SelectedDate

blah blah...
}
```

However, as the control is in the gridview edit template, I cannot find a way to access this to C#, compared to if the calendar was just an element on a normal asp.net page.

Thanks

Comment: If you have `cal_SelectionChanged` as the event handler on the control, can't you just use the `sender`? (It should be the calendar control itself - you will just need to box it to the correct type)

Comment: Would you mind posting an example? I am unsure of what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to be aware, controls within `Template` based controls (such as `<asp:Repeaters>`) cannot be accessed directly as you would a control placed directly into a page / usercontrol / masterpage.  It is possible to find it using the "FindControl" on the specific item within the control, but there should be an easier way...

In this case you should be able to set a `SelectionChanged` event handler on the calendar control to the function in your code-behind.  (This is assuming you're using the inbuilt [Calendar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) Something like...

```
<asp:Calendar runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="cal_SelectionChanged"> ... </asp:Calendar>
```

When an event such as this is called, the object that caused the event (in this case the calendar control) is passed into the function through the `sender` parameter.

This means that instead of trying to work out which calendar was clicked, you simply can do this...

```
cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Calendar cal = (Calendar)sender;
  date = cal.SelectedDate;
  blah blah...
}
```

Comment: Thanks freefaller. That makes perfect sense. There is a textbox next to the calendar control in the gridview edit pane when the user clicks edit. Is there an easy way to get the selected date appear in the textbox? Again, the issue is I cannot access the textbox. Normally I would do textbox.Text = date.toString(); or something along those lines.

Comment: @Mike91, are you talking about within the same function as above?  If so, try something like (untested)... `TextBox txt = (TextBox)cal.Parent.FindControl("myTxtId");`  **!UPDATE!** Use the `cal`, don't use `sender`

Comment: I tried to use sender before and it did not work. I tried the 'cal' technique instead and it worked great. Many thanks for your time freefaller!!

Comment: You're welcome @Mike91, good luck with the rest of your project :-)